# Clang doesn't work

Tags: ios, clang, theos

I am having an issue with clang on my iPhone 6s running iOS 10.1.1. This error is also present when I try to compile a theos project.

COMMAND:
clang test.c -isysroot /var/theos/sdks/iPhoneOS8.1.sdk -o test

ERROR:
ld: library not found for -lSystem
clang-3.7: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation).

I have tried to google it a couple of times and had no luck. Please help.

Comment: ld is the linker.  You are missing a library or have not specified the path to the library..

Comment: So which library should I include and how?